# Parsing strings with regex into different patterns

Tags: regex

Could someone show me a correct syntax. The complete string should consist of only numbers and characters and whitespaces in each pattern except in type. The type and one parm are mandatory. The whitespaces before and after `>` `:` are mandatory. The whitespaces after `,` are mandatory. Several parameters as well as nodes are optional.

```
GOOD
type : param
type : par am, para m > no de
type : param > node
type : param, param2 > node
type : param, param2, param3 > node

NOTGOOD
type:                             <<< no param
type: param                       <<< because no whitespace after type
type : param,                     <<< , to much
type : param, param, > node       <<< 1 , after second param to much
type : param, param >> node       <<< 1 > to much
```

Thats what i ve now:

```
^(?<type>(\w+(\s)*))\s+:\s+(?<params>.+\S*?)(?<node>\s+>\s+(\w|\s)*?)*$
```

Comment: `^(?<type>.*?)\s+:\s+(?<params>(?:.*?,\s+)+)>\s+(?<node>.*?)$` should work.

Comment: sorry it wont match with it do u use any Special tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
"^(?<type>\w+)\s+:\s+(?<params>\w[\s\w]*(,\s+\w[\s\w]*)*)(\s+>\s+(?<node>\w[\s\w]*)*)?$"
```

You didn't give an example with multiple nodes, so I didn't know how they would look. This only allows spaces in-between them. If they should have commas, then make the "node" matching group the same as the "params" matching group.

Based on your latest comments, it seems that each param and node can have multiple "words" but no leading or trailing spaces. This also implies that there's only **one** whitespace character after each `:`, `,`, and `>`. If this is true, then try this variation of the regex:

```
"^(?<type>\w+)\s+:\s(?<params>\w([\s\w]*\w)*(,\s\w([\s\w]*\w)*)*)(\s>\s(?<node>\w([\s\w]*\w)*)*)?$"
```

Comment: seems to work just once type : param,  >> node how can i prevent this ? there is a space after the last comma!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A line like "type : param, >> node" will not match. That's what you want, because it has an extra comma, right?

Comment: yes the extra comma alone wont work that s right but if u do extra comma + 1 whitespace it break! means all param and nodes should not have whitespace at start and end some like trim...

Comment: See my newest revision. Hopefully this will fit your requirements so you can officially accept my answer. Thanks!